# Active Directory DirectorySearcher is not returning all of the available properties

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am writting a new progam for my boss that will replace this old VBS that they are currently using.

So the program is suppose to go into the AD and collect the Name of all the employees and their email addresses. My problem is that each user has around 60ish properties assigned to them but my program is only pulling in 32 fields, one of which is the CN which is half of what I need. Of course mail is not one of the properties being imported. I have also noticed while debugging that I think is is only bring in the emlpoyees from the Long Island branches and not from everywhere which I dont understand why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! =D

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory; 


namespace EmailListing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            DirectoryEntry adFolderObject = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=PHF Users,DC=phf,DC=inc");


            DirectorySearcher adSearchObject = new DirectorySearcher(adFolderObject);
            adSearchObject.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;



            adSearchObject.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=user)(!description=Built-in*))";




            foreach (SearchResult adObject in adSearchObject.FindAll())
             {
                 //mail = adObject.Properties["mail"].ToString();

                Console.Write(adObject.Properties["cn"][0]); 
                Console.Write(".        ");
                //Console.WriteLine(mail);





             }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
    UserPrincipal foundUser = found as UserPrincipal;

    if (foundUser != null && !foundUser.Description.StartsWith("Built-In"))
    {
        string firstName = foundUser.GivenName;
        string lastName = foundUser.Surname;
        string email = foundUser.EmailAddress;
    }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: First off I would like to say I LOVE YOU! I have been searching everywhere, going on forums, youtube and nothing. This worked! getting the email addresses and the names. THANK YOU!

One last question how do i filter it to just have users. When I add the if statement I get errors, is the if statement the filters?

Comment: @user1873179: by specifying a `UserPrincipal` class as your "search argument" (`qbeUser`), you're telling S.DS.AM to search for only users.

Comment: is there a way to get the accounts that have email addresses. I am seeing names and no email addresses. Id like to only have users that have email addresses to show up.

Comment: Figured it out, you just got to put whatever you want to filter in the if statame, ie. foundUser.EmailAddress != null

Comment: @user1873179: exactly - that's why it's called *query-by-example* - you just provide an example (or a template) of what you're looking for...

Comment: Quick question, I have the AD set at just domain which i am guessing is the whole AD. How do I pick a specific OU to look at?
Do I have to do it in the (contextType.Domain)?

Comment: @user1873179: look at the various overloaded constructors of `PrincipalContext` - you can define a `container` (e.g. an OU) to use with one of them

Comment: Do you know how to pull the current user logged on? I want to add a security check which pulls the current user and check

Comment: @user1873179:  do you mean `UserPrincipal.Current` ?

Comment: so had to go into a meeting and ddnt finish heres the full message. Will userprincipal.current pull the user logged on, ie me if i run the program right now?

Comment: @user1873179: first of all : **YES** - why don't you just try it? And second : [read the fabulous online docs on the topic!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.aspx) - it's there for you - just read it and see what those properties and methods are and do .... *UserPrincipal.Current -- Gets a user principal object that represents the current user under which the thread is running.*